# SSRS how to show pre-calculated totals

Tags: reporting-services

I have a data like

[image]

which comes from SSAS. Amount_YTD and Amount_YTE values are as Measures.
YTDs are Year-To-Date values, and YTEs are Year-To-End values regardless of Month filter.

My report design is

[image]

So, with this design, YTD and YTE values are SUMed (naturally) and what I get is

[image]

So row and column totals and grand totals are not as expected. This is what I would like to achieve,

[image]

(some rounding may occur)

How can I get "Expected" report?

Answer (score 0):

For ALI you need to use MAX instead of sum for YTD and MIN instead of sum for YTE looking at your data.

For your other two summary lines toplam and Genel Toplam I would alter your ssas query so that it gives YTD and YTE figures regardless of both customer and month and use these figures in the YTD and YTE columns

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use MAX/MIN as you mentioned. For other two summary lines, I figured it out using lookup function.